# Cannot set the paper size

Tags: vba, excel

Below is the code tied to an activeX button.

```
With Worksheets("SUMMARY").PageSetup
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
    .CenterFooter = "Page &P of &N"
    .PrintTitleRows = Rows("1:7").Address
    .RightFooter = ""
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .PaperSize = xlPaperLedger 'Error 1004
Worksheets("SUMMARY").PrintOut
End With
```

For some reason, I keep getting a `1004 error` at the `.PaperSize = xlPaperLedger` line. The printer supports the Ledger paper, and I can print it manually, but for some reason it won't print when I click the button.

There are a lot of password protected sheets and the like, but I don't think this is the issue. I have printed before with this code, and it worked fine.

Comment: Try with .PaperSize = xlPaperSize.xlPaperLedger

Comment: Can you include the error message?   The error codes are harder to follow.  Try using the [macro recorder](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html), to print manually.  Then you can compare the VBA Excel writes with your own.

Comment: Error message was 1004 Unable to set the PaperSize Property of class Page Setup.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the print driver.  Each print driver calls the paper size something different.  Printing to Adobe PDF printer for example calls it `xlPaperLedger`.

But when printing to an HP printer using an HP universal print driver you need the following code:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.PaperSize = 120
```

You can find out what your printer calls it by recording a macro and manually setting the papersize within Excel.

**TL;DR:**
Some print drivers like it called different names.

Answer (score -2):

Even though you can print manually, this could still be a printer driver issue. You could try installing the 32/64 bit version of the printer driver (dependent on which you currently have) to see if that makes a difference

Comment: Although I didn't downvote this answer I can guess why others did.  Link only answers are frowned upon.  Why?  What happens if the link breaks?  Also is *suggest trying the drivers* really an anwser?

Comment: Well, I think your point about the link is valid. 

However, the link details what to do with the drivers, and I thought it would be easier for the OP to read it, rather than me retype it for the sake of pedantry.

I also am trying to help the OP, by pointing him to a place with a person who has experienced exactly the same issue. Not sure why this attracts criticism.

Comment: The argument against that is; what happens when someone else encounters the same issue a year from now.  They find this page.  Will the link still work?  If they have to visit another site is this *really* an answer?  Or is it just internet clutter?  I only point this out because often fixing an answer results in downvoters removing their downvote (and therefore restoring your lost rep).

Comment: I tried the drivers, and it did not work. I ended up just going through and setting the page as a Ledger and removed the line of code entirely. The printer detects it as 11x17 and prints accordingly, with no issues.